# Encoding issue in Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, character-encoding, dhis-2

I'm using DHIS2 which is a `WAR` file. It seems to serve static content (JS files) and there seems to be an encoding issue. I have very little experience with Tomcat and I'm wondering if this is an application issue, a configuration issue or a server issue.

The JS files seem to output like so:-

```
var objectNames =��[],
dimConf = conf.finals.dimension;
```

Comment: Tomcat version?